# How to get original accessor data when update Model Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, accessor

I want to write before and after data to logs table when updating an instance.

I'm getting beforeUpdate(original) data by `getOriginal()` method, but I don't know how to get data related to original data.

Ex:

Table `campaigns` has field `campaign_status_id`.

I have an Accessor is `getCampaignStatusNameAttribute()`, this method will get relationship between `campaigns` table and `campaign_status` table and return `campaign_status_name`.

If I update campaign status and call `getCampaignStatusNameAttribute()`, I just receive updated data only. Of course, I can write a custom function and pass the `campaign_status_id` as a param to get data but I want to know any better solutions.

Any solution to get the original Accessor?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the original data, you use

```
$model->getAttributes()['column_name']
```

or this

```
Arr::get($model->getAttributes(), 'column_name', 'default_value_here') // default value can be null
```

Make sure to import this `Arr` helper facade at the top if you're using the `Arr` way. The advantage of the `Arr` way is that even if the value doesn't exist, it would not return any error and you can always return some default value if the value didn't exist.

`getOriginal` will return the modified if it was called recently. That's not really the most reliable way.